# Вывод видеокарт *всех* + жестких дисков + перевод в GB

Tags: c#, консоль, деление, winworms

Прошу помочь перевести байты в ГБ. А также нужно вывести весь список видеокарт, у меня на ноутбуке их две, а выводит одну.
КОД:

```
// Tyt videocards
static string GPUid()
        {
            var gpuname = (from z in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Name FROM Win32_VideoController").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                           select z.GetPropertyValue("Name")).FirstOrDefault();
            return gpuname != null ? gpuname.ToString() : "Unknown";
        }


 
// Tyt delenie
static string disksize()
        {
            var disksize = (from b in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Size FROM Win32_DiskDrive").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                            select b.GetPropertyValue("Size")).FirstOrDefault();
           disksize = Convert.ToInt32(disksize) /= 1048576;
            return disksize != null ? disksize.ToString() : "Unknown";
        }
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` - откуда второй взяться...

Comment: `ManagementObjectSearcher` является Disposable. Нужно обязательно освобождать ресурсы.

Comment: То есть? Как освободить? И для чего?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А как сделать группой? Не FirstorDef?